# How do I load an asset bundle?

Tags: unity, assets, streaming-assets

I am trying to load a bunch of prefabs from an asset bundle.  I am building the asset bundles for `StandaloneWindows64`:

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(BuildPath, BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64);
```

I load my asset bundle using Unity's new web request system:

```
var www = UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(Url);
yield return www.Send();
if (www.isError)
{
    Debug.LogError(www.error);
    yield break;
}
var bundle = ((DownloadHandlerAssetBundle)www.downloadHandler).assetBundle;
```

However, my bundle does not have my asset bundle in it.  It only has the manifest:

```
//Output:  "1 asset: bundlemanifest"
Debug.Log(bundle.GetAllAssetNames().Length + " asset: " + bundle.GetAllAssetNames()[0]);
```

If I look at my manifest, I can see my asset bundle names `"structures"` does exist:

```
ManifestFileVersion: 0
CRC: 3317959940
AssetBundleManifest:
  AssetBundleInfos:
    Info_0:
      Name: structures
      Dependencies: {}
```

I tried retrieving it from my [AssetBundleManifest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundleManifest.html):

```
var manifest = bundle.LoadAsset<AssetBundleManifest>("assetbundlemanifest");
```

But the AssetBundleManifest only has functions which return `string`s and `Hash128`s.

How can I instantiate the prefabs in my asset bundle named "structures"?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing with the results of `BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles` and where `Url` points (in your web request).  `BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles` returns a manifest and then `BuildPath` is where the bundles are created.  Note that each bundle also has a corresponding .manifest file that can be ignored in most cases; the actual bundle wont have an extension and that's the file you want to load.

Comment: I also noticed you tagged the question with "streaming-assets".  If you're putting the bundles in `Application.streamingAssetsPath`, you don't need to deal with `WWW`, you can directly call `AssetBundle.LoadFromFile`.  (`WWW` creates excessive amounts of garbage so only use it if you must)

Comment: @GuntherFox I am taking the asset bundles/manifests/etc and putting them on a local server.  I am then using the URL of that local server.

Comment: Does your URL include the underscore and the hash for the actual bundle file?  When you build a bundle named "structures" it will create two files: one named `structures.manifest` and one named `structures_XXXXXXXX` where the X's are a hash.  You want to make sure you're downloading the one with the underscore, hash, and no file extension.

Comment: @GuntherFox OK.  I have no idea.  This is where I am stuck?  I cannot find access to my structures.  The only reference I can find to it is the string name of it, which is not helpful.

Comment: You'll need to analyze the results of `BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles` by saving its return value like so: `AssetBundleManifest manifest = BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(BuildPath, BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64);`.  Then you can inspect that manifest and get the actual name of the bundle files that were created via `manifest.GetAllAssetBundles()`.  The strings that function will return are the names of the bundles themselves and will have the format: "bundleName_bundleHash".  That's the string your url should end with.

Comment: @GuntherFox I am not being clear.  I have done that.

Comment: Okay!  So if you've got the proper file being uploaded/downloaded once you have your `AssetBundle` (from `var bundle = ((DownloadHandlerAssetBundle)www.downloadHandler).assetBundle;`) you should then be able to use [`bundle.LoadAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAsset.html) to load a specific asset from the bundle.

Comment: @GuntherFox And this is where I am failing.  It's all coming up null.  The asset bundle says it only contains the manifest, and not the actual assets themselves.

Comment: What have you done to assign assets to their bundles?  Did you use the option in the inspector to assign each asset you'd like to bundle into its correct bundle or have you done it programmatically?

Comment: @GuntherFox I did it in the inspector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54131/discussion-between-evorlor-and-gunther-fox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My URL required the name of the asset bundle at the end of it.  I had the parent folder as my asset bundle's name, which loaded the Asset Bundle Manifest for some reason.